# Using Regular Expressions to isolate the relevant portion of a long title

Tags: python, regex, string, 3d, render

TITLE = `MANTRA (IFD & RENDER): mh 104_IJ_5070_Fireworks_residualSmoke_v3 (/obj/FX_jet_contrails/_RENDER/smokeResidual_Beauty) (Frames: 1001-1151)`

I want to isolate the **"mh 104_IJ_5070_FireWorks_residualSmoke_v3"** portion of this title using a regular expression, but I'm struggling to figure out a clean way to do it.

Any ideas?

**Python 2.7 please**

Comment: So, I'd say give more examples of titles. Are the titles always going to be `2 characters`, followed by a `_` separated identifier?

Comment: KATANA RENDER: abr char_nasr_main_lookdev_v002 (Layers: turntable_head) (Frames: 1001-1200) (Time: ~30 min) (Tpl: v004)

Comment: SHOTBOT KATANA RENDER: abr MC0825_main_layout_v001 (Layers: bty_grey_qc) (Frames: 1001-1185) (Time: ~15 min) (Tpl: v005)

Comment: MATCHMATION RENDER: abr MS0255_main_matchmation_v001 (Layers: output) (Frames: 1001-1052)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you can change, so what you need to anchor your regex on.

Personally I would avoid regex if you can help it - they just create a lot of bugs.

Try:

```
 " ".join(str.split()[6:8])
```

Split the string into words and then grab the 6th and 7th word and put them back together.

If you really want to use regexp

```
import re
r = "TITLE = (?P<title>.*): (?P<data>.*) \((?P<path>.*)\) \(Frames: (?P<frame>.*)\)"
m = re.match(r, str)
m.groupdict()

{'path': '/obj/FX_jet_contrails/_RENDER/smokeResidual_Beauty', 'frame': '1001-1151', 'data': 'mh 104_IJ_5070_Fireworks_residualSmoke_v3', 'title': 'MANTRA (IFD & RENDER)'}
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me because this is a tool that will analyze tons of different titles, it doesnt always look like this. But Im always trying to isolate the information seperated by _ so regex is going to be necessary.

Comment: Added the regex - but it all depends on what changes and what stays the same, and which bits are the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the first portion of the title `MANTRA (IFD & RENDER):` doesn't change, and that the two parts you want to extract contain no whitespace characters, the following should work:

```
import re
title = "MANTRA (IFD & RENDER): mh 104_IJ_5070_Fireworks_residualSmoke_v3 (/obj/FX_jet_contrails/_RENDER/smokeResidual_Beauty) (Frames: 1001-1151)"
substring = re.search(r": (\S+ \S+)", v).group(1)
print(substring)
```

Yields:

```
'mh 104_IJ_5070_Fireworks_residualSmoke_v3'
```

This effectively grabs everything after the first colon + space `:` and captures the first two sections of non-whitespace characters.